# How robust is `func(*argument)`?

Tags: python, jython, cpython, python-stackless

In python, you can expand a sequence into discrete function arguments with the star operator:

```
args = [2, 3]
print(pow(*args))  # same as `print(pow(2, 3))`
```

There's even a nice idiom for transposing a matrix (a list of lists), like this: `zip(*matrix)`. Since the matrix could have many, many rows, I wonder: How robust is the star-expansion of very long sequences into arguments? In many languages, *explicit* argument lists (`f(a1, a2, a3, ..., ..., ...)`) have length limits well below array length limits.

Are there such limits in (popular implementations of) python, and are star-expanded arguments handled in a way that prevents hitting against such limits? (E.g., if they are directly stuffed into an argument vector for a function with signature like `def function(*args)`). Is this an implementation-dependent issue, or are there guarantees about what can be handled? I dug around the python documentation a bit but I was not able to find discussion of this.

Comment: I am not aware of any such limits, however if you have a matrix with many many rows you should really be using numpy and the `.T` property for transpose, not mucking around with zips and splats.

Comment: Thanks, the answers to the linked question cover it between them (or by implication). @wim, I didn't plan to. The idiom made me nervous, so I wanted to know the facts.